# Finding the conditional pmf of a random variable X

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ have the pmf $p(x) = (\frac{1}{3})(\frac{2}{3})^x$, $x = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots,$ zero elsewhere. Find the conditional pmf of $X$ given that $X \geq 3$.

We have $$P(\{X = x\} \mid \{X \geq 3\}) = \frac{P(\{X = x\} \cap \{X \geq 3\})}{P(\{X \geq 3\})} = \frac{P(\{X = x\} \cap \{X \geq 3\})}{1 - P(\{X < 3\})} = \frac{P(\{X = x\} \cap \{X \geq 3\})}{1 - \left[(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{2}{3})^0 + (\frac{1}{3})(\frac{2}{3})^1 + (\frac{1}{3})(\frac{2}{3})^2\right]}.$$

I am not sure how to handle the probability in the numerator. Also, the answer is simply

$(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{2}{3})^{x-3}$, $x = 3, 4, 5, \ldots,$ which makes me think that my method is not correct. How did the author arrive at this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint probability in the numerator is simply $$\Pr[(X = x) \cap (X \ge 3)] = \begin{cases} \Pr[X = x], & x \ge 3 \\ 0, & x < 3. \end{cases}$$  To see why, simply choose a value for $x$:  for example, if $x = 4$, then the event $(X = 4) \cap (X \ge 3)$ is equivalent to $X = 4$.  But if $x = 2$, then the event $(X = 2) \cap (X \ge 3)$ is the null set.  It is an impossible event, whose probability is zero.

Comment: Thank you! When I calculate the denominator, it is 8/27, which we can pull out of the numerator as (2/3)^3, which gives us exactly the author's answer. I think he assumed 0 elsewhere, which is why he didn't have a piecewise function like yours.